# VScode doesn't suggest unused declarations

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, unused-variables

I'm making a flutter app with VScode and I have a lot of unused variables declared at the top of the code, but it doesn't show me the underline. Is there a way to setting this?

P.D:The rest of unused code works.

Thank you!

Comment: try `flutter pub get`

Comment: @pskink where is that file?

Comment: @pskink it seems I don't have it...

Comment: @SamChan doesn't work. I think this is for the imported packages, not declared variables.

Comment: so check [The analysis options file](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file)

Comment: @pskink wow! we are on the right way... I see that is there a lot of config options there! Do you know what is the one that helps me?

Comment: `unused_local_variable: warning`

Comment: but apparently it is not working for global variable which is your case? ("*and I have a lot of unused variables declared at the top of the code*")

Comment: @pskink Yes, it doesn't work for globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart linter and analyzer have no rule for unused global variables, only for local variables. Here is all available rules and diagnostic messages:

https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#diagnostics

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/

**So answer is**: you can't do that.

There is an open issue on github about opportunity to add custom rules, you can track it - https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/697